KNN search By ID in Kibana
Say I have an index with the following mapping:
{
  "test-2": {
    "mappings": {
      "properties": {
        "advert_id": {
          "type": "integer"
        },
        "fraud": {
          "type": "boolean"
        },
        "photos": {
          "properties": {
            "id": {
              "type": "integer"
            },
            "vector": {
              "type": "dense_vector",
              "dims": 3,
              "index": true,
              "similarity": "l2_norm"
            }
          }
        },
        "rating": {
          "type": "long"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

Here is how my data is saved in Elastic:
 {
    "advert_id": 123,
    "fraud": true,
    "photos": [
      {
        "id": 456,
        "vector": [
          213.32,
          3.23,
          4.21
        ]
      }
    ]
  }

I want to search data with similar vectors by id.  I wrote a function with 2 queries by first searching the id and then doing the KNN search but it seems not a good approach. Is there a way in Elastic Search that I can directly search similar vectors without an external script or do nested queries so that I can directly fetch the result on Kibana? Any help is appreciated.
def vectorSearchByID(myID): 
    firstQuery= {
        "query": {
            "match": {
                "id": myID
            }
        }
    }
    res= client.search(index="test-2", body=firstQuery)

    if res['hits']['hits']:
        vector = res['hits']['hits'][0]['_source']['photos']['vector']
    else:
        return 
    
    secondQuery= {
      "knn": {
        "field": "photos.vector",
        "k": 1,
        "num_candidates": 5,
        "query_vector": [213.32, 3.23, 4.22]
      }
    }
    res = client.search(index="test-2", body=search_query)
    return res

I thought this is possible because here it says I can combine multiple queries: I need to an Elasticsearch Query with subquery
But the problem is I don't know how to store the vector found from the first query and pass it to the second one.

In your example photos is an object and you are using an array in your example for some reason. Do you expect it to work with multiple photos/vectors per document in your setup?
